# PyQt5 TableView. Как уменьшить ячейки в таблице и текст в них

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я отображаю БД через TableView. Я реализовал маленькое окно с таблицей для отображения, но текст в ячейке не подстраивается и не уменьшается. Я хочу, чтобы я имел возможность уменьшить текст в ячейке и возможно саму ячейку. Думаю обойдусь без минимально воспроизводимого примера, понять бы где и чем уменьшать текст.
Пробовал
self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSize(5, 5)
self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1)
Не помогает...
[image]

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? Уменьшать шрифт отдельной ячейки? А если в ячейке полный текст "Война и Мир"?

Comment: Игорь, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример и лучше объясняйте что вы хотите сделать. Вы пишите что хотите уменьшить текст в ячейке, а надо писать о том что вы хотите получить и хорошо бы как-то показать как выглядит то, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Ну например как в том же Word, можно уменьшить шрифт с 14 до 12. Мне вот такой аналог нужен. Да и я понимаю, что «Война и мир» не влезет, все в рамках разумного)